# Duplicate Check On fail what do I return to ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a repository pattern implementation of MVC.

I am checking if the users email exists and if it does I want to return something to the `Actionresult` but I'm un sure as to what.

```
 public void CreateCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        bool duplicate = false;

        _ctx.AddToCustomers(customer);

        var txt = customer.Email;

        duplicate = CheckDuplicate(txt);
        if (!duplicate)
        {
            _ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
```

On my Do something, would it be like a http Exception? and how would I handle it on the ActionResult side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller action method, you may return a model error and show that in your view.

```
ModelState.AddModelError("","Customer already exists");
return View(customer)
```

Assuming your view has the helper methods to show the error details to the user.

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
```

If you have the duplication checking in a different method, you may return an appropriate value indicating there is a duplicate record exists/everything worked as expected. You can have an enum/class as your return type or you can throw a custom exception back to the calling code.

#### Custom class as return type

```
public class TransactionResponse
{
  public bool IsSuccess { set;get;}
  public string ErrorType { set;get;}
  public string ErrorDetails { set;get;}
}
```

and use this class as your return type

```
public TransactionResponse CreateCustomer(Customer customer)
{
  //if success
  return new TransactionResponse { IsSuccess=true};
  //if error
  return new TransactionResponse { ErrorType="Duplicate"};
}
```

Another approach is throwing an exception.

#### Throwing custom exception

```
public class DuplicateException : Exception
{
  public DuplicateException(string message):base(message)
  {
    
  }
}
```

and in your method, when you know a record already exists, throw an instance of our exception

```
if(duplicate)
{
  throw new DuplicateException("Customer exists");
}
else
{
  //save
}
```

and in your calling code, handle this exception and do the needful(show message to user)

```
public ActionResult Create(CustomerViewModel model)
{
  try
  {
    //call the code to your other method here
    //If everything is succesful, Redirect (PRG pattern)
    return RedirectToAction("CustomerCreated");
  }
  catch(DuplicateException ex)
  {
    //Show error message to user. ModelState.AddModelError or any other means

  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    // some other error happened. deal with that now
    // to do :log the error
  }

}
```

Comment: What namespace is the ModelState in as this is just my data layer

Comment: With the CreateCustomer method in my data layer, I was thinking I could pass some thing back to the controller that i could then deal with, and then implement the ModelState.AddModelError

Comment: Thank you I'm sure I can get something to work from here. thanks